# How to get localhost server to return JSON instead of HTML in node.js

Tags: node.js, json

I receive the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 6
> at JSON.parse ()

I understand that the server is returning HTML, when the client expects parsed JSON. I am using a localhost server. How do I get the localhost server to return JSON instead of HTML?

Here is my code below:

```
// required modules
const https = require('https');

// json files link
const mimeURL = 'https://gist.github.com/AshHeskes/6038140#file-file-extension-to-mime-types-json';

const getMimeType = extension => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(mimeURL, response => {
            if(response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
                reject(`Error: Fail to load mime types json file: ${response.statusCode}`);
                console.log(`Error: Fail to load mime types json file: ${response.statusCode}`);
                return false;
            }

        let data = '';
        // receive data by chunks
    response.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
  });
//   once you received all chunks of data
      response.on('end', () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(data)[extension]);
        });

    }).on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(e);
    });
});

};
module.exports = getMimeType;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you are requesting isn't JSON, it's a formatted  element hosted on a Github Gist. To get the Raw JSON, you need to click the raw button next to the Gist title:
[image: Where to find the RAW button on a Github Gist]

Make requests to the [raw JSON URL](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/AshHeskes/6038140/raw/27c8b1e28ce4c3aff0c0d8d3d7dbcb099a22c889/file-extension-to-mime-types.json), and it will work.

Here's the code for your specific case:

```js
// required modules
const https = require('https');

// json files link
const mimeURL = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/AshHeskes/6038140/raw/27c8b1e28ce4c3aff0c0d8d3d7dbcb099a22c889/file-extension-to-mime-types.json';

const getMimeType = extension => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(mimeURL, response => {
            if(response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
                reject(`Error: Fail to load mime types json file: ${response.statusCode}`);
                console.log(`Error: Fail to load mime types json file: ${response.statusCode}`);
                return false;
            }

        let data = '';
        // receive data by chunks
    response.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
  });
//   once you received all chunks of data
      response.on('end', () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(data)[extension]);
        });

    }).on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(e);
    });
});

};
module.exports = getMimeType;
```

Comment: your answer resolved my problem - thank you!

Comment: Hi @novycody, glad to hear I could help! In that case, you can click the checkmark next to the top of the post. This shows the community here that this answer solved your problem, as well as giving a little bit of reputation to yourself (and myself). Thanks!

Comment: Will do and thanks for the tip as I learn to navigate this super helpful forum.

Comment: @novycody Glad to hear it! Have a nice day.